# PHP or CSS, div moves when refresh

Tags: php, html, css

I have a div "infcont or welcome" in my page that changes position every time I refresh the page.
It oscillates between two positions.
The page has been written in html with PHP(Session script) in it, and CSS included page.
I don't know if the problem is in the css page or in the php script.
PHP

```
<link href="stile.css?1500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Embed Google font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<?php
   session_start();
?>
```

HTML

```html
  <section id="slider">
    <div id="sfondoc">
    <div class="infcont">
    <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Benvenuti!</h1>
    <div class="login">
<form method="post" id="form" action="login.php">
<div class="divw">
<ul class="form-style-1">
<li>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="field-dividedww"  value=""  maxlength="20" placeholder=" username" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" class="field-dividedwp"  value=""/  maxlength="20" placeholder=" password" />
   </li>
<li>
<input type="submit" id="loginsub" value="LOGIN" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="news">
<h1>News</h1>
<div id="news1">
</div>
<div id="news2">
</div>
<div id="news3">
</div>
<div id="news4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```css
.infcont {
     position:relative;
     top: 130px;
     left: 20px;
     width:100%;
     height: 100%;
}

.infcont .welcome {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align:left;
    width: 45%;
    min-height: 48%;
    background: #032322;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.infcont .news {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 60%;
    width: 35%;
    background: #032322;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.infcont  .news h1
{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Raleway_Thin;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:white;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px ;
}

.infcont .welcome h1 {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Raleway_Thin;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:white;
}

.infcont .welcome h2 {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Raleway_Thin;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:white;
}

.infcont .welcome .login {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:12%;
    margin 0 auto;
    width:70%;
    height: 200px;
    background:#d46a43;
}


.infcont .welcome .login .divw {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top: 40px;
    left:50px;
    width:80%;
}

.infcont .welcome .login .divw .form-style-1 .field-dividedww, .field-dividedwp{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

#loginsub {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #032322;
}

#loginsub:hover {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0e1d17;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to get code samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
.logged_out {
    margin-right: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

link:-[HTML button moving on page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584258/html-button-moving-on-page-refresh)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand why, and in which point is the error.